# Regex in JavaScript to reject 3 consecutive characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to Regex and would be great if someone can help me to write a JS regex to reject 3 consecutively repeating characters.

Comment: Please explain more about it. Where do the consecutive characters start? Can you post a sample string?

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. Sting could be "aaaQuicknnnBrownFoxggg" I need to detect are there any consecutive characters anywhere in the string.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to start learning regex.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I will have a look on that site

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The regexp:

```
/(.)\1\1/
```

will match a string containing three repeating characters.